# Trying to create an index for bookings in a hour training

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, restful-architecture

Im making an application where an user can book a hour of training. I want to give the user the option to see who is booked in the training (hour), i'm making the index bookings in a training, this is my code:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
    @booking.training_id
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created"
      redirect_to trainings_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end


  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Book deleted"
    redirect_to trainings_path
  end



private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end

end
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true



end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get    '/book',                 to: 'bookings#new'
  post   '/book',                 to: 'bookings#create'
  delete '/unbook',               to: 'bookings#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :users
end
```

When i go to training show (a specific hour of training) the code is the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
  </center>
```

The _index_bookings.html.erb is:

```
<ul class="bookings">
<% if current_user.bookings(@training) %>
  <li>
<%= link_to @training_id, training_bookings_path %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The app gives me the error:

> Showing
>   /home/cesar/Apps/boxApp/app/views/bookings/_index_bookings.html.erb
>   where line #4 raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bookings", :id=>"7"}
>   missing required keys: [:training_id]

I would like to know why it does not take the training_id, if it is taking the id of the class which is 7. And how to fix it.

Comment: try adding changing it to this: `training_bookings_path(@training)`

Comment: thanks, it worked. God bless you

Comment: glad to help! i added it as an answer, now that we know it works. if you could accept the answer when you get a chance, it'll help other users who have the same problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using nested resource urls, you should pass the parent resource as the first parameter, like so:

```
training_bookings_path(@training)
```